# У меня на виндовс 10 после запуска быстро вылазит синий экран смерти

Tags: windows, экран

У меня не роботает сброс настроек не работает защита виндовс и не запускается безопасный режим ну и команда мрт не работает у меня быстро вылазит синий экран смерти с кодом System Service Exception помогите что делать?

Comment: Как вариант - просто переустановить с нуля, быстро и просто.

Comment: Загрузитесь с флешки с другой операционной системой. Работает? Сделайте тест памяти. Работает? Переставьте ОС с нуля.